# What is the "distance" of a random walk on a graph?

Tags: markov-process, graph-theory, random-walk, social-network

What is the definition of the `distance` of a random walk? In the `Statistical significance of a cluster` of [this](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-10-283) paper, and [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/from-random-walks-to-personalized-pagerank/) blog, they both mention the `distance` of a random walk.

I think it should be a different concept from the `length` of a random walk.

Comment: it would help if your title mentioned that you're talking about the random walks on graphs, it's very different from an ordinary RW. in this case your papers mean by distance is the length of a walk on a graph as measured by edges walked

Comment: @Aksakal But in the blog with visualization, clearly length and distance are two different quantities.